# Is it possible to have 2 label in one button

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

this is my button

```
- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {

}
```

my problem is, when i click startBtn with START label on it, the process is start but the label is change to CANCEL for cancel the process. i don't want to make 2 button that is START and CANCEL, i just want to put it all together into one button that is startBtn.

Any help?
Thank you for sharing your knowledge for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// set titles in viewDidLoad Method or in interface builder
[button setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateSelected];


- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;

    if (button.slected) {
       // start process
    }
    else {
      // stop process
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {
     [button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)cancelBtn:(id)sender {
     [button setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: that means i add 1 extra button and put it at same place with my startBtn, right?